# Possibly 2000's animated show, mc may have power to change parts of his body to tech guns? His friend is a talking chimpanzee? wears red hat

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

There used to be some show as a kid I watched. 2000's animated show, I think it was a cartoon network show, and was even on Netflix.  I don't remember much about the main character, all I can remember is he was probably in his early 20's or late teens. I'm not 100% sure how accurate this is but I believe he could transform his arms or body parts into tech weapons or the sort. He also had either a monkey that was intelligent and could talk as friend or some weird monkey looking guy that he hung out with, either way Mr. monkey or chimp wore a red fez hat

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What was the setting of the story?  Who did the main character fight with these weapons?

Comment: i added all information i know about it

Answer (score 7):

[Generator Rex](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/GeneratorRex)?

> The plot focuses on an amnesiac 15-year-old boy named Rex, who gains the ability to produce bio-organic machines from his body due to a global incident known only as "The Event", which caused nanomachines called Nanites to infect every living thing across the planet, causing random mutations.

[image: Rex, his monkey wearing the red fez, and a guy who looks like an agent]

Comment: @user171489 - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. It will also reward Laurel with some additional reputation.